# No WiFi with Loki and Intel Dual Band AC 3168 card

Tags: wifi, networking

I am attempting to make the switch from Windows to Linux, and decided to give Elementary a try. I installed Loki, but I and unable to get WiFi working. It did not work when I booted from the install USB, and it didn't work after I installed it. I'm working with an MSI laptop, with an Intel Dual band Wireless-AC 3168 card.

The kernal of Elementary that I have installed is:

```
4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I run rfkill list all, my results are:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no    
Hard blocked: no
```

When I run sudo lshw -class network, my results are:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
description: Network controller
product: Intel Corporation
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
version: 10
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:df200000-df201fff

*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
logical name: enp3s0
version: 10
serial: 4c:cc:6a:dc:41:31
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
resources: irq:128 memory:df100000-df13ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

From what I'm seeing, Elementary just isn't seeing the WiFi card, or at least isn't seeing it correctly. I Googled various solutions for a couple of hours, but didn't find anything that worked. Does anybody have an idea about what I can do to solve this?

I hate to say it, but if I can't resolve this, Im either going to have to try a different Linux Distro, or just plan on sticking with Windows for now.

Thanks for any help of advice you can offer.

Answer (score 2):

At the time I am writing, the most current stable kernel is 4.10.8. MSI laptops with Killer Networking are reportedly working on recent Linux kernels. Their [support page](http://www.killernetworking.com/driver-downloads/knowledge-base?view=topic&id=2) says so.

Try updating your Linux kernel. Easiest way is probably via [Ukuu](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/ukuu-kernel-upgrade-utility.html).

If it helps, I'm running elementaryOS Loki on an MSI Leopard Pro GP62M-7RD and everything works fine after updating the kernel.